# How to Resolve Conditional Operation Failed Error in SSIS Derived Column Transformation?

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I'm attempting to read a flat file containing all string values in a pipe "||" delimited format.  Some of the fields are null and I receive the above error in my Derived Column Transformation when evaluating the following expression:

```
ISNULL(ExternalUsedDeductibleAmount) ==  TRUE  ? 0.00 : (REPLACENULL((DT_DECIMAL,2)
(DT_R4)ExternalUsedDeductibleAmount,0.00))
```

Since the flat file may or may not contain a value in this field, I want to add the value 0.00 if the field is null.  I originally tried using just REPLACENULL but have since reviewed guidance that I needed to evaluate the field for Null values as part of the expression.

How do I rewrite the expression such that the Derived Column transformation passes a default value of 0.00 when the source data column is null?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data in the .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition in the derived column should be like below :

```
(ExternalUsedDeductibleAmount == "") ? "0.00" : ExternalUsedDeductibleAmount
```

Keep in mind that you need to convert the column `ExternalUsedDeductibleAmount` to the appropriate data type of your destination (using the `Data Conversion` component)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I actually did the type cast within the Derived Column expression.  Data Conversion from string to float to decimal was not working for me, even with two separate transforms.  Your expression did the trick, in tandem with setting RetainNulls = True in the Flat File Source transform.